# Shell Script to Loop through CSV file, run oracle update query and check for successful completion

Tags: shell-script

I am new to shell scripts. I want to loop through the records and run update query. I tried the code below, but it is giving errors.

Value of $data below is

**14/06/2021(type date) ,30914 (type number)**

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $UP <<EOF
for data in `cat Store_Days_To_Open_$exeDate.csv | sort --unique `
do
     business_date=`echo $data | cut -d \, -f 1`;
echo $business_date
     store=`echo $data | cut -d \, -f 2`;
echo $store
UPDATE sa_store_day SET store_status= 'W' , data_status = 'P', audit_status='R' WHERE store= $store and business_date= $business_date;
done
commit;
exit
EOF
```

Comment: Can you reveal the errors? And are `(type date)` and `(type number)` part of the $data value? Also, I am not familiar with sqlplus; can it execute shell scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix shell and sql commands. At least `sqlplus` will not interpret shell commands. You can try something like:

```
>outfile
for data in `sort --unique Store_Days_To_Open_${exeDate}.csv`
do
     business_date=`echo $data | cut -d \, -f 1`;
echo $business_date
     store=`echo $data | cut -d \, -f 2`;
echo $store
echo "UPDATE sa_store_day SET store_status= 'W' , data_status = 'P', audit_status='R' WHERE store= $store and business_date= $business_date;" >>outfile
done
echo exit | $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $UP @outfile
```

Comment: Thanks Romeo Ninov. It is working fine. How do I check the total number of records updated?

Comment: you can use something like `wc -l outfile` (if one `update` update one record). Or you can capture the output of `sqlplus` and count from there

Comment: @Amit, if you are fine with the answer feel free to accept it :)

Comment: the code works perfectly for me.. Thanks a lot for your help !!!